# Instalar Frameworks sin Composer en el servidor

Tags: composer

Necesito instalar un framework (PHP-Auth) en mi servidor, pero no tengo acceso a la consola. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Tengo entendido que si hago la instalación en mi ordenador y luego copio la carpeta vendor, ya no necesito volver a instalarlo en el servidor, pero no sé ni cómo hacerlo ni donde.

Si no es necesario descargar XAMPP mejor, porque me llevaría mucho tiempo.

Comment: No sé si esto es lo que buscas: https://php-download.com/ Es extraño que no tengas acceso a tu propia máquina (no mencionas si es un windows o un linux), pero que si puedas instalar xampp. Aunque es más sencillo conectarte por ssh o pídele a tu proveedor si te puede dar el acceso por ese medio.

Comment: Mi sitio web lo tengo en un servidor con cPanel donde no tengo acceso a SSH y tampoco puedo instalar XAMPP. Estoy preguntando si puedo instalar composer en mi PC de casa, luego instalar el framework y subir los archivos (u otro método mejor si lo hubiese).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado y comparto mi solución:

He instalado XAMPP en mi PC y luego he descargado el instalador de Composer para Windows.
Después de instalar XAMPP, le he dado a instalar Composer, y cuando me pedía seleccionar un archivo PHP, seleccionaba el que genera XAMPP en su instalación.

Después he abierto la CMD (Busca "cmd" en el buscador del menú de inicio de Windows) y he ejecutado el comando "composer", esto me indica que sí está instalado porque aparecen todos los comandos.

Ahora puedes instalar cualquier framework o librería, y tan solo tendrás que ir a la carpeta donde se guardan los archivos y copiar todos los archivos que ha generado, entre ellos el archivo composer.json y la carpeta vendor. Se sube al hosting y listo.